# Netty ChannelHandlerContext writing from different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm making a real time game using Netty, and I have a question about using the write method on a `ChannelHandlerContext` from a different thread than the `ChannelHandler` is in.

I have a separate pool of threads in the Java application where I'll be pulling from the database and doing the game logic. I want to use a `BlockingQueue` to submit requests to a different thread to pass the `ChannelHandlerContext` and data that the player sent. That thread will then make changes to the game state based on that. After that's done, I want to be able to write back a response to the user with the changed game state using the `ChannelHandlerContext` write method.

If I do this from the separate game logic thread, I don't want the write function to burden that thread. If I call write from there, will it spawn it's own thread, use the game logic thread, or use the `ChannelHandler's` Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case `ChannelHandler` thread will be used. This is because `ChannelHandlerContext.write` method checks what thread you are in. And if `ctx.write` method is called from the outside thread (not the event executor thread) than the `ctx.write` operation will be submitted to the  thread that belongs to your context.

What actually happens could simply described like this:

```
gameLogicPool.send(new Runnable() {
         //your logic here
         ctx.write(response);
         //ctx.write actually does this when executed from another thread:
         ctx.executor().execute(new Runnable() {
             //write happens here when you are in event executor already
             }
         );
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok. So just to be clear calling ctx.write from a different thread will use the same thread pool as my channel, and won't spawn a new one or use the thread that it's currently in?